# Find an isomorphic series to a normal series.

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Find an isomorphic series to normal series

$0\trianglelefteq \langle 8\rangle\trianglelefteq \langle 2\rangle \trianglelefteq Z_{32}$. (1)

I have tried this one 
$0\trianglelefteq \langle 16\rangle\trianglelefteq \langle 4\rangle \trianglelefteq Z_{32}$.But the factor groups of these two series are not isomorphic.

So, is it possible to find an isomorphic series to (1)?

Comment: What is you definition of "isomorphic series"?

Comment: Two subnormal series {Hi} and {ki} are isomorphic if there is a 1-1 correspondence between the collection of all factors {Hi+1/Hi} and {ki+1/ki}. The corresponding factors must be isomorphic.

Comment: In (1), the collection of factor groups are {<8>/{0}, <2>/<8>, $Z_{32}$/<2>}

Comment: In that case your proposed answer is correct. In both the given series, and in your series, the factors are cyclic 4 twice, and cyclic 2 once.